# Change List Item Text Dynamically in a ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a combobox that is filled with Site names. When an item is selected, the user is able to edit the site information. If they modify the name of the site, I want to update this in the combobox list. I have seen that I can remove the item, and re-add it, but I don't want to change the order, I only want to change the text of the selected item.

Is there an accesseser that allows the text in a combobox list item to be modified?

Comment: yes `combo.Items(N)`.  you will have to save an index into Items for the one they select, then if they change the text, change that item to the new text

Comment: @Plutonix - I swear I tried that first thing and it didn't work. However, when I did it this time, it did exactly what I wanted. I must be tired. Thank you.